# jquery - Get contents of other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

This is my function:

```
        $.get(profileAddress, function(data){
            alert(data);
        })
```

The alert displays sourcecode of page `profileAddress`.

How can I get for example first `div` from that "data"?

I need to get specific `div` from that `profileAddress` page and display it on my page.

I know how to do second part. I only need help on how to get `div` from that data that is passed to that function.

Comment: What are the conditions of this specific div? Does it have a particular id? Is it the first div of a certain class?

Comment: Who not set that returned html to a hidden div and access the div you want from there?

Comment: An aside: 'Specific' has got to be the most commonly misspelled word on this website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something along the lines of this will give you the div you're interested in:

```
var selectedDiv = $(data).find('selector_for_div');
```

Then you could append it after one (or more) elements like so:

```
$('selector_for_element_to_append_after').append(selectedDiv);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$(data).find("div").first();
```

Comment: you need to wrap data with $() in order to use the .find()
Oh and casing is important.